# trying to deploy sencha app for android .Not able to figure out the error in this build

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch

trying to deploy app on android but build command showing an unknown error

```
stspl@stspl-System-Product-Name:/var/www/html/tourism$ sencha app build -run native
Sencha Cmd v5.0.3.324
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : native
[INF] Using GPL Version of Ext JS version 2.4.0.487 from /var/www/html/tourism/touch.
[INF] The implications of using GPL version can be found here (http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/licensing).
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[WRN] C1000: Rhino Parse Warning (Trailing comma is not legal in an ECMA-262 object initializer =>  },) -- /var/www/html/tourism/touch/src/ux/RatingField.js:112:2
[WRN] C1000: Rhino Parse Warning (Trailing comma is not legal in an ECMA-262 object initializer =>          }]) -- /var/www/html/tourism/touch/src/ux/RatingField.js:143:4
[INF] Concatenating output to file /var/www/html/tourism/build/temp/production/mytour/sencha-compiler/cmd-packages.js
[INF] writing content to /var/www/html/tourism/bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to /var/www/html/tourism/bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to /var/www/html/tourism/bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to /var/www/html/tourism/bootstrap.js
[INF] Appending content to /var/www/html/tourism/bootstrap.json
[WRN] C1015: callSuper has no target (this.callSuper in Ext.Container.setParent) -- /var/www/html/tourism/touch/src/Container.js:406
[WRN] C1015: callSuper has no target (this.callSuper in Ext.Container.doSetHidden) -- /var/www/html/tourism/touch/src/Container.js:1270
[WRN] C1014: callParent has no target (this.callParent in Ext.Decorator.setDisabled) -- /var/www/html/tourism/touch/src/Decorator.js:157
[WRN] C1014: callParent has no target (this.callParent in Ext.data.ArrayStore.loadData) -- /var/www/html/tourism/touch/src/data/ArrayStore.js:64
[WRN] C1014: callParent has no target (me.callParent in Ext.dataview.DataView.onAfterRender) -- /var/www/html/tourism/touch/src/dataview/DataView.js:892
[WRN] C1015: callSuper has no target (this.callSuper in Ext.event.publisher.TouchGesture.publish) -- /var/www/html/tourism/touch/src/event/publisher/TouchGesture.js:178:7
[WRN] C1014: callParent has no target (this.callParent in Ext.fx.animation.Wipe.getData) -- /var/www/html/tourism/touch/src/fx/animation/Wipe.js:119:7
[WRN] C1015: callSuper has no target (this.callSuper in Ext.layout.Default.setContainer) -- /var/www/html/tourism/touch/src/layout/Default.js:63
[WRN] C1015: callSuper has no target (this.callSuper in Ext.layout.Fit.onContainerSizeFlagsChange) -- /var/www/html/tourism/touch/src/layout/Fit.js:29
[INF] Concatenating output to file /var/www/html/tourism/cordova/www/app.js
[INF] merging resources into /var/www/html/tourism/cordova/www/resources
[INF] merged 0 resources into /var/www/html/tourism/cordova/www/resources
[INF] merging resources into /var/www/html/tourism/cordova/www
[INF] merged 0 resources into /var/www/html/tourism/cordova/www
[INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime
identical ../css/app.css 
[INF] Copying page resources to /var/www/html/tourism/cordova/www
[INF] Writing content to /var/www/html/tourism/cordova/www/microloader.js
[INF] Appending content to /var/www/html/tourism/cordova/www/microloader.js
[INF] Building output markup to /var/www/html/tourism/cordova/www/index.html
[INF] Writing content to /var/www/html/tourism/cordova/www/index.html
[INF] [Cordova] Attempting Cordova Build for platforms "android"
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/www/html/tourism/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:435: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/www/html/tourism/.sencha/app/packager-impl.xml:17: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/www/html/tourism/.sencha/app/cordova-impl.xml:77: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/home/stspl/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.0.3.324/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:655: shellscript returned: 1
```

Comment: You've got a couple of Javascript warnings, and sometimes that can stop the build. Have you tried fixing those? You can also use `sencha -d app build` to get debugging information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem. The problem was with the `debug.keystore` file in `.android` folder.

Go to the `cordova` folder of your project and in console give : `cordova -d compile`

If you see the error info with expired file
Go to `C:\Users\(Your name)\.android` and delete file `debug.keystore`.